# How to make button displayed from 7:30am-9:30am everyday

Tags: javascript

I know how to make the button appear if the time is hourly:

```
if ((hr == 7) || (hr == 8) || (hr == 9)) {
                displaybutton.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
```

But I'm not sure how to do it if I want to set it up at 7:30am to 9:30am instead of 7am to 9am.

Comment: You just need to use time parser that allow it to you. Like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for example

Comment: Is this something that need to be checked everytime or it's only one time request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function(){
 DisplayCurrentTime();
};
    
function DisplayCurrentTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
  var ampm = (hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";

  time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        
  if(hours>=7 && hours<10 && ampm=="AM")
  {
    if(minutes<=30)
      {
        var lblTime = document.getElementById("time");
        lblTime.innerHTML = time;
        $("#idbuttontoshow").css({"display":"block"});
      }
    }
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="two"></div>

<br>

<div id="time"></div>

<div id="idbuttontoshow" style="display:none;">

<button>one</button>
<button>two</button>
<button>three</button>

</div>
```